# What is the correct title of the 'Off-canvas navigation menu' design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

For a report I'm describing all the mobile design patterns used in my design and I should use the correct names. However, I can't find the correct title for the 'off-canvas navigation menu', a menu that is mainly hidden, but shown by a click of a button (often a 'hamburger' icon'), such as in the (old) Facebook iPhone app.

P.s. If possible link the library which confirms your answer. (Which might help me seek other titles as well.

Comment: Patterns have 'correct titles' now?

Comment: Well in fact each pattern may or may not have a few aliases, but each, or at least the rather common ones,  do have their own recognizable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call that a Toggle menu, a la Brad Frost's design patters library:
http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/sHvaz